# noVNC Docker with Jmeter - start button error, Could not create script recorder - keytool error: java.security.ProviderException

Tags: docker, jmeter, performance-testing, blazemeter, novnc

I am running Jmeter in noVNC, able to run Jmeter in noVNC but offcourse in default small window.
But when I create Http(s) script recorder and when click on Start button, I get this error

error is -> "Could not create script recorder -see log for details: >> keytool error: java.security.ProviderException: Could not initialize NSS << command failed code:1
'keytool -genkeypair -alias:root_ca: -dname"CN=_Jmeter Root CA for recording(INSTALL ONLY IF IT IS YOURS).......FULL ERROR in SCREENSHOT"'"

Tried creating Http(s) script recrorder with and without PRoxy setup in my Chrome browser, getting same error.

[image]

right hand side of screenshot
[image]

below is my Dockerfile

```
FROM uphy/novnc-alpine
RUN \
    apk add --no-cache curl openjdk8-jre bash \
    && apk add --no-cache nss \
    && curl -L https://archive.apache.org/dist/jmeter/binaries/apache-jmeter-5.4.1.tgz >  /tmp/jmeter.tgz \
    && mkdir -p /opt \
    && tar -xvf /tmp/jmeter.tgz -C /opt \
    && rm /tmp/jmeter.tgz \
    && cd /etc/supervisor/conf.d \
    && echo '[program:jmeter]' >> supervisord.conf \
    && echo 'command=/opt/apache-jmeter-5.4.1/bin/./jmeter' >> supervisord.conf \
    && echo 'autorestart=true' >> supervisord.conf
ENV JAVA_HOME /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8-openjdk/
RUN export JAVA_HOME
```

This is how I am running (related to [Use Jmeter desktop application as web app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67419731/use-jmeter-desktop-application-as-web-app/67424394?noredirect=1#comment119187646_67424394))

1. creating docker image with noVNC and running Jmeter inside noVNC (dockerfile also provided in the end)
2. exposing it to some port and accessing it in browser

```
docker build -t jmeter .
docker run -it --rm -p 8080:8080 jmeter
```

3. I checked my docker container also, able to see **JDK**, jdk is already present here -> **/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8-openjdk/** and jmeter is present here **/opt/apache-jmeter-5.4.1**
4. I am not sure should I pass more options or arguments inside docker run command.
5. I am wondering, how this jmeter will create the certificate inside my **bin** directory on click of **start** button, since this Jmeter is running inside noVNC docker ?
6. Any other way by which we can automatically integrate/create this certificate without importing or without clicking on **start** button.
7. How Proxy setting can be done if Jmeter in running inside noVNC container.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to [install `nss` package](https://pkgs.alpinelinux.org/package/v3.3/main/x86/nss)

change this line:

```
apk add --no-cache curl openjdk8-jre bash \
```

to this one:

```
apk add --no-cache curl openjdk8-jre bash nss \
```

Once you re-build the image the HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder should launch normally.

With regards to the certificate, it will be stored in JMeter's "bin" folder **in the container** so if you want to use in in the browser in the container - you will have to install the browser there as well.

If you want to use the browser on your local machine - you will need to [copy the certificate from the container](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/cp/) and to [expose another port](https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/container-networking/) for JMeter's HTTP(S) test script recorder.

Just in case be aware that you can also record JMeter test scripts using [JMeter Chrome Extension](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/the-new-blazeMeter-chrome-extension-v4-easily-script-jmeter-and-selenium), in this case you won't have to worry about proxies, certificates and ports.

Comment: Hi Dmitri, i tried running with below line in docker but no success, getting same error as posted in Question. 

 apk add --no-cache curl openjdk8-jre bash nss \

Comment: any body can help in this ?